# increase array size and insert element at last index

Tags: java, arrays, loops

i have dynamic array size. i want to increase the size by 1, and insert a new element at the last index array. how to do this? for example now: my array size is 2, when i do looping, i increase the array size by 1  and try to insert a new element at the last array. i've tried below code but the looping stop whenever hit the empty array. i want something like this: array[0]=value, array[1]=value, array[2]=remarks

```
            while (z <= array.length+1){

            System.out.println("z: "+z);

            value  = array[z];

                str_value += value  + ",";

                if (array[z] == null){

                    str_value += remarks + ",";
                    continue;
                }

                System.out.println("value: "+value );                   
        z++;
        }
  System.out.println("str value: "+str_value);
```

Comment: why are you using an array and not a List?

Comment: Java arrays are not dynamic. Use a `Collection` like `ArrayList`, it's backed by an array but it's dynamic.

Comment: How do you declare you array? Since Java arrays (not array elements) are immutable their dimensions (once defined) cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot resize a java array (without copying/creating a new one) . Seems like you are looking [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which is a dynamic array in Java. For your reference here is an example:

```
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    al.add("JAVA");
    al.add("PERL");
    al.add("SQL");

    //get elements by index
    System.out.println("Element at index 1: "+al.get(1));
```

Comment: i've tried using array list and it solves my problem. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You do not add to an array by referring to array[array.length() + 1]. That will just give array out of bounds error.

As others said, you cannot add an empty element to an array.

If you need to create a dynamic array, you should consider some sort of list, probably an ArrayList in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `System.arraycopy()`

```
int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
int[] b = new int[5];

System.arraycopy( a, 0, b, 0, a.length );
```

You can add the extra element to second array and then copy

Link to the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) for reference